# jQuery issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm using this function as an address book module, for selecting any employee from the sidebar it display all the content of the employee. It works fine in Chrome but not in IE. I'm not able to run the src variables declared in this function in IE. Please suggest me some other ways to declare these type of variables so that these will be compatible to all browsers.

```
function singleSelect(id)
 {           
  if(flag){  
     unCheckAll();
     userIds="";
     //userIds= document.forms['frmSidebarSearch'].elements['userIds'].value + id +",";
     var src = ($("#"+id).attr("src") === "<@core.basePath/>images/chk-box-img.gif")
                        ? "<@core.basePath/>images/chk-box-img-tick.gif" 
                        : "<@core.basePath/>images/chk-box-img.gif";
      $("#"+id).attr("src",src);
      var src2 = ($("#anchor"+id).attr("class") === "")
                        ? "selected" 
                        : "";
      $("#anchor"+id).removeClass().addClass(src2);
       var elementss = document.getElementById("all").getElementsByTagName('img');
       for(i=0;i<elementss.length;i++) {
             if($("#"+elementss[i].id).attr("src") === "<@core.basePath/>images/chk-box-img-tick.gif"){
             userIds=  userIds  +"," +elementss[i].id; 
              }
         }
      unHilightAll();
      highLightIndex(id);
      document.forms['frmSidebarSearch'].elements['userIds'].value=userIds;
      $('#frmSidebarSearch').ajaxSubmit({target:'#content',url:'<@core.basePath/>sp/manager/manageraddressbook/manager/'+id});
    }
    flag = true;
  }
```

Comment: can you show the html as well?

Comment: I'm using Free Marker Template Language(FTL), and the code used for FTL is:------>

<a id="anchor${user.id}" href="javascript:;" onClick="singleSelect(${user.id});"   class=""  >

and after selecting from the sidebar it converted into
:--->

<a id="anchor${user.id}" href="javascript:;" onClick="singleSelect(${user.id});" class="selected"  >

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with double equals (I think triple equals sign is only in languages like php).

```
(condition == condition) ? true : false;
```

Comment: yeah i tried double equals also but they doesn't effect the functionality

Comment: Does the `<@core.basePath/>` get parsed before the javascript is called? That would force the src to always be `false`.

Comment: Thanks
yeah it get parsed and works fine, the only problem is the compatibility to IE

Comment: Have you tried de-bugging with IE developer tools? [developer tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359) I know jscript on IE can be slightly different to javascript